# I'm trying to get REST API call working with Priority Software

Tags: priority-web-sdk

This is my call's URL:

`https://us.priority-software.com/us3/odata/Priority/tabpe01n.ini/init51/FNCLOG?$select=FNCNUM,FNCTRANS,FNCIREF1,FNCIREF2,VFES_FNCITIREF,CREDIT1,DEBIT1,DC,SUM1,DETAILS,ACCNAME,ACCDES,KLINE,USERLOGIN,UDATE,vfes_udate$filter=UDATEnevfes_udate`

What I'm trying to achieve is to pull records only when the 'UDATE' doesn't equal to 'vfes_udate'.

I'm getting this error:

0000: {"error":{"code":"400","message":"Term 'FNCNUM,FNCTRANS,FNCIREF1
0040: ,FNCIREF2,VFES_FNCITIREF,CREDIT1,DEBIT1,DC,SUM1,DETAILS,ACCNAME,
0080: ACCDES,KLINE,USERLOGIN,UDATE,vfes_udate$filter=UDATEnevfes_udate
00c0: ' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression.","target":"",

Now, I have a feeling my syntax is incorrect. I don't know if I can use a $filter after a $select.

Any ideas, anyone? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A. What does "vfes_udate" stands for?
Is it a custom filed added to Priority's FNCLOG form? If so, make pay attnetion that it is case sensitive, usually fileds on Priority are in Capital letters.

B.There should be an "&" sign before $filter paramter and spaces (or %20) between the parts of the filter.

C. As much as I know, you can't filter comapring 2 Priority fields. You need to compare it to a constant value.

try this:

https://us.priority-software.com/us3/odata/Priority/tabpe01n.ini/init51/FNCLOG?$select=FNCNUM,FNCTRANS,FNCIREF1,FNCIREF2,VFES_FNCITIREF,CREDIT1,DEBIT1,DC,SUM1,DETAILS,ACCNAME,ACCDES,KLINE,USERLOGIN,UDATE,vfes_udate&$filter=UDATE%20ne%20vfes_udate